# how do i loop on computed field to make it's computed method change if one field related False?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

i make a computed field char that get values as strings from fields but empty field get False as string , i need when any field equal False ignore it from computing ?

i tried to make a model_field as example if false do another compute method

```
  @api.one
  @api.depends('car','model','dsc','drc','year','org')
    def _compute_amount(self):
    for self in self:
        if self.model.name:
            self.model= False
            self.name = str(str(self.car.name) + " " + str(self.dsc.name) + " " + str(self.drc.name) + " " + str(self.year.name)+" " +str(self.org.name))
        else:
            model=self.model
            name = str(str(self.car.name) + " " + str(self.model.name) + " " + str(self.dsc.name) + " " + str(self.drc.name) + " " +str(self.org.name)+ " " +str(self.year.name))
```

the value of my code that all field be false when model_field is false

Comment: Check the field value before concatenation, `self.org.name if self.org else ""`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not even remotely close to what you should do to get your value, try learning Python basic for example looping and conditioning before you jump to code in a framework. Meanwhile, check following code, should serve your purpose

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('car','model','dsc','drc','year','org')
def _compute_amount(self):
  name_fields = ('car','model','dsc','drc','year','org')
  for record in self:
    computed_name = ""
    for field in name_fields:
      field_value = getattr(record, field)
      if field_value:
        computed_name += field_value.name
    record.name = computed_name
```